# How to search external text document for words

Tags: python, list, spyder

I need a function count_word that receives a word and prints how many times the
word is in the file “speech.txt”. And we are to assume that the only punctuation speech.txt will have commas and dots.

```
def count_word(word):
    counter = 0
    with open("speech.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.replace(",.", " ").lower().split()
            if word.lower() == line:
                counter += 1
    return(counter)

print("a", count_word("a"))
```

I edited the code accordingly but the function still returns 0 when it should be 4, what else is causing it to fail?

The image is the speech text that we need to process.

[speech text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTj2j.png)

Comment: `strip` doesn't do what you probably think it does. Calling `replace` method to replace each punctuation by an empty string should work better.

Answer (score 2):

`strip` only removes the characters from the ends. You can use `re.sub` or `str.replace` to remove all punctuation anywhere.

After splitting, you get a list of words, so use `count` to find out how many times the word appears in the line instead of trying to compare the word with the list itself.

```py
words = re.sub('[,.]', '', line).lower().split()
counter += words.count(word.lower())
```